# How to group join with linQ

Tags: linq, join, grouping

I need to join two lists by an Id in order to map values to an User entity.

For that part, I think I've managed to do it with :

```
 var concernedParticipantIds = baseValues.Select(x => x.ParticipantId).Distinct().ToList();
                var queryParticipants =_unitOfWorkMt.GetMTReadonly<Participant>().GetQuery(tenantId).Where(x => concernedParticipantIds.Contains(x.Id));

                var participantAndValues = from value in baseValues
                    join participant in queryParticipants on value.ParticipantId equals participant.Id 
                    select new {Participant = participant, Value = value};
```

But it results in one line per Value like this :

```
user_1 => value_1
user_1 => value_2
user_1 => value_3
user_2 => value_1
user_2 => value_2
user_2 => value_3
...
```

Is there a way to group by the user? I'd like something like :

```
- user_1 => value_1  
          value_2
          value_3
- user_2 => value_1
          value_2
          value_3
```

The only thing I came up with is something like

```
 var results = from p in participantAndValues
               group p.Value by p.Participant into temp
               select new { Person = temp.Key, Values = temp.ToList() };
```

Seems to work but not sure it's the right way, and maybe there's a way to do it in one query?

Comment: Just like `group` has an `into`, so does `join` - which translates to the `GroupJoin` method. So use `join`...`into participantJ` then `Values = participantJ.ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GroupJoin`:

```
var participantAndValues = from value in baseValues
    join participant in queryParticipants on value.ParticipantId equals participant.Id into paricipantJ
    select new {Participant = participant, Values = participantJ };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this way

```
var results = from p in participantAndValues
               group p by p.Participant into g
               select new { Person = g.Key, Values = g.ToList() };
```

Or as a non-query expression:

```
var results = participantAndValues.GroupBy(p => p.Participant)
                                  .Select(g => new { Person  = g.Key, Values = g.ToList() });
```